# Looking for references on infinite groups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, infinite-groups

I am interested on infinite group theory. Well, I found many references, but all of them consider any particular structure: abelian groups, finitely generated groups, topological groups (particularly profinite groups), Lie groups, ...

Do you know some references treating infinite groups in general? Thank you.

Comment: Without additional hypotheses, it's just too general.

Comment: Perhaps offer what you've seen already, so as not to get repeats?

Comment: There is a kind of meta-mathematical saying that says that any statement concerning all groups is either trivial or false (I have heard it attributed to Gromov, but it's probably not true). Basically, if you want to say something interesting, you have to restrict to a certain class of groups, otherwise groups are too complicated to have general theorems that always hold.

Comment: I never knew that @CaptainLama! Seems like "no solution" is a sufficient answer, you should post it!

Comment: There is nothing to say, as it essentially boils down to just "what can I derive from just the group axioms" (which is basically just trivial things). Also the statement that is attributed to Gromov was actually in reference to finitely generated groups (maybe even finitely presented groups), so even in the finitely generated case there is not much to say.

Comment: I edited my comment since it may have been misleading : it's not a "result" in the mathematical sense, it's more of a general empirical constatation.

Comment: Among the books of "Group Theory", the two volumes by Kurosh concern finite as well as infinite groups simultaneously, almost for all the concepts in group theory. It is much devoted towards infinite groups (just read preface of it, to realize it). This could be a primary reference for infinite groups.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend the two volumes of Derek Robinson [Finiteness Conditions and Generalized Soluble Groups (Part 1 and Part 2)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540056203) which are probably discontinued, but possibly available in a math library near you. They are an excellent source to start with. Part 2/Contents I found on-line in [.pdf](http://tocs.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/8960878X.pdf) format. Note that a lot of research on finite groups has been inspiring the research on infinite groups. That is why certain classes or even varieties of groups are studied. To this end also the book of Hanna Neumann [Varieties of Groups](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642886010) makes an interesting read.

Comment: They have come back with both the volumes now, it is avaliable on amazon.com

Comment: Thanks, I did not know. I have have two old volumes on my shelves and still use them!